# Get location after the screen is switched on after screen saver

Tags: cordova, geolocation

I am developping a Phonegap app and I need to record the position of mobile users every 5 minutes when the end-user is using the app (I am not really interested to get the position when the app is in background). So far I use this function:

```
setInterval(function() {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_onSuccess, geo_onError);
}, 1000 * 60 * 0.1);
```

Remark: it is set 0.1 instead of 5 (for 5 minutes) for testing purposes

This works fine till the screensaver is activated. When I switch on the screen, the function geo_onSuccess is then no more called.. I just get a timeout error through geo_onError 1 time. How could I make this plugin working (restarted?) after the screen is switched on? Or is there any other method to periodically record position of mobile user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some event handler to your project:

```
var geoInterval;

document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

function onResume(){
   geoInterval = setInterval(function() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_onSuccess, geo_onError);
      }, 1000 * 60 * 0.1);
}
```